# How do I load data into a div that is on another view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a main view that has jQuery that gets data from a partial view and then I want to display this data in the main view.  Here is the main view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).data('url'),
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                    $('#search').html(result);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my partial view:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div id="search">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click the button on the main view, it calls an Action Method that returns the `PartialView`.  When the `PartialView` is loaded, it should put data in result into `search`, but it is not doing it.  The data is in the alert, so I know it is there, but I am probably doing something backwards.

Comment: what is being returned in result?

Comment: @MattBodily - Result is what is in the partial view, the html you see in the post.

Comment: from what you have posted, you are taking result and putting it into the the div with ID 'search'.  but you're saying that div is being returned in result.  sounds like you have a loop.  you should have a div on your main page that is being loaded with the partial view that is being returned in your ajax call

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you have shown. Do you have an element with `id="search"`? What does `console.log($('#search').length);` return? What type of element is it?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you want to attach the partialview to one div that is contained in partiaview himself, and not in a div in the main view, this is the trouble...

Main View must contains

```
<div id="search"></div>
```

javascript on main view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).data('url'),
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                    $('#search').html(result);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Partial View returned by URL built thanks to "$(this).data('url')"

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```